# How can I tell what version of OS X I'm on from the command line?

Tags: osx, ssh, version

I frequently find myself SSHing into various OS X machines, and it'd be useful if I could tell what version of OS X I was on when I'm doing that. `uname -a` doesn't quite work, since Darwin kernel versions don't always change with the rest of the system.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### `sw_vers`

My suggestion is to use `sw_vers`.  Example output as of 10.6.4:

```
> sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.6.4
BuildVersion:   10F569
```

The answer that suggested `system_profiler | grep 'System Version'` is what I have tried to use in the past, but it has 2 problems.

1. It is slow since it generates a full system_profiler dump of the machine, gathering all hardware and software inventory information.
2. The output of system_profiler has changed over time.  e.g. output of `grep` for 'Serial Number' on 10.6.4 is "Serial Number (system): ZNNNNNZNZZZ", whereas on 10.4.11 it was "Serial Number: ZNNNNZNZZZZ" - importance being the parse-ability of the output and the add " (system)" piece can be problematic unless you are expecting the change.

Comment: I'd flip this around. 

```
Use sw_vers
…
---------------------------
The answer that suggested `system_profiler`…
```

Comment: @TimVisher Agreed. I just edited his answer to put it at the top.

Answer (score 38):

The easiest way is:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.6.4
```

From http://tinyapps.org/blog/mac/201008140700_os_x_version_terminal.html:

> ```
> $ sw_vers
> ProductName:    Mac OS X
> ProductVersion: 10.6.4
> BuildVersion:  
> 10F569
> $ sw_vers -productVersion
> 10.6.4
> ```
>
> Especially handy when resetting a password in single user mode, since the method varies based on which version of OS X is running.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out Benjamin! I've updated the post to include checking an offline OS X install like so: `grep -2  ProductVersion /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`. Aloha, Miles

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
 system_profiler  | grep 'System Version'
```

*Mike Gray's answer is better than this. Please see that*

Comment: what Mike Gray said.

Comment: Single-user mode `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` wins where `sw_vers` loses.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Blog article with instructions [*How to Get the Mac OS X Version in a Shell Script*](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/cli/how_get_mac_os_x_version_shell_script)

```
OS_VERSION=`/usr/bin/defaults read "$3/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion" ProductVersion`
echo "$OS_VERSION"
```

Comment: This is very useful for finding the version of a non-active operating system, eg. a volume that is being repaired or such.

Answer (score 3):

The `system_profiler` can be run as `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType`. No need to grep through huge output.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/228103)

Comment: @JeffSchaller looks the answer is fine. It does an answer to the question.

Comment: It determines the version of OSX?

Comment: Perhaps it’s meant to be a comment of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584/117549?

Comment: Yes, it does return in "System Version" part, see [OS X Version from Command Line](https://scottlinux.com/2011/11/18/os-x-version-from-command-line/), it is an answer to me instead of a comment IMO.